# Dynamics 365 and Sharepoint Integration , Deleted Sharepoint Site from Dynamics 365

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

I have a SharePoint site which integrated to Dynamics 365 for document storage (both are on-premise).

The SharePoint site record in Dynamics 365 is deleted and when we recreated the integration, I cannot see the documents and users have no access to the documents.

How should we get back to the old state? What are the steps?

All files are on the SharePoint site. We expected recreation of the site record in Dynamics 365 and setting it as default should get back the structure, data and settings (including user access).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back to the old state after deleting a SharePoint site record in Dynamics 365, you will need to recreate the site record in Dynamics 365 and set it as default. This should restore the structure, data, and settings, including user access.

To recreate the site record, you can follow the steps in the "Enable SharePoint Integration" section of the reference article. Once the site record is recreated, you can set it as default by following the steps in the "Actions on SharePoint Location Records" section of the same article.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/integrate-sharepoint?view=op-9-1#in-this-section